# Loss in history dictionary different from what printed on screen during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

**System information**
Using TensorFlow 2.8.0

**Describe the current behavior**
After calling "history = model.fit(...)", values saved in history.history['loss'] and history.history['accuracy'] are different from the ones printed on-screen at every epoch during training.

I have a custom training loop with the `train_step()` function returning 2 losses: d_loss and g_loss.
The values turn out to be different when I call `model.fit()` -

```
Epoch 1/2
110/110 [==============================] - 33s 294ms/step - d_loss: -1.5941 - g_loss: 2.2890
Epoch 2/2
110/110 [==============================] - 32s 288ms/step - d_loss: -2.5873 - g_loss: 2.8013
```

```
print([round(x, 4) for x in history_init.history['d_loss']])
print([round(x, 4) for x in history_init.history['g_loss']])
```

OUTPUT:
d_loss: [-2.7844, -2.2764]
g_loss: [2.4266, 3.3268]

**Describe the expected behavior**
Values should be the same, as is with previous tf versions and with other parameters.

There has been a previous discussion on this and a bug raised, but it seems to be back from tf2.4.1: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48408

Comment: The way this question seems to be written is like a bug report, if there is a bug in TF, then wait for the developers to fix it, not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: It was reported as a bug for tf2.4 and it says it was fixed in a tf-nightly, but it doesnt work in tf2.8 either. I put up the question on stack overflow to know if there is a work around or if I am missing something.